# Como puedo convertir un archivo XML a Excel usando C# Asp.Net (aplicación de consola)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo el control de un Xml guardado en una variable `string` y necesito poder convertirlo a un archivo excel. si pueden ayudarme le agradezco de ante mano.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor agrega qué intentaste hasta el momento. además, ¿porqué dices en tu pregunta "aplicación de consola", pero usas la etiqueta [tag:asp.net]?

Comment: Revisa el siguiente enlace: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13808590/3613462